# Error remote connection from Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, tnsnames

I am trying to connect to my Oracle Database 11g from another computer connected in the same network.

In the connection data I put the address of the server machine, but it does not allow me the connection. From the server machine if it allows me to connect, but not from another computer:

**`Error de E/S. The network adapter could not establish the connection`**

> Machine 1 - Oracle Server: Local access connection: Yes
>
> Machine 2 - Client Remote connection: Failed

Both machines are in the same network segment:
192.168.x.machine1
192.168.x.machine2

```
Listerner
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LAPTOP-BPS592UE)(PORT = 1521)(QUEUESIZE = 32))
    )
  )
```

Status LISTENER:

```
C:\..\..\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 22-JUN-2018 11:30:17

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                22-JUN-2018 11:04:36
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 25 min. 40 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\..\..\..\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\..\..\..\diag\tnslsnr\LAPTOP-BPS592UE\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=LAPTOP-BPS592UE)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=LAPTOP-BPS592UE)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 3 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Did you install Oracle instant client on machine 2? .Most probably firewall issue ,try to run this command "tnsping xe" on machine 2.

Comment: On machine 2 I am trying to connect with SQL Developer.

Comment: Try TNSPING and let us know the results. Also, you posted the Listener data, but is your client using TNSNAMES to connect or...? Is that set properly? Can you ping your server from your laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the solution to problem:

Add Windows Firewall Exception to:

> Oracle_home\bin\oracle.exe - Oracle Database executable
>
> Oracle_home\bin\tnslsnr.exe - Oracle Listener